# How to rasterize a single feature with the feature ID with `gdal.RasterizeLayer`?

Tags: python, gdal

I would like to rasterize a single feature from a vector with many features using `gdal.RasterizeLayer` in Python. This is what I have been trying:

```
gdal.RasterizeLayer(
    raster, [1], layer, burn_values=[1],
    options=['WHERE="FID=1"'])
```

But I get a raster that has ALL the features in `layer` rasterized onto it. How can I rasterize just the feature with feature id 1?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the layer to create an in memory layer with the feature you want then use it instead to burn your feature geometry to raster. See below code to grasp the idea

```py
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

shapefile = "ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp"

layer = gdal.OpenEx(shapefile)
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate("", layer, format="Memory", where="FID=1")
copied_layer = ds.GetLayer(0)
print(copied_layer.GetFeatureCount()) # To check filter applied to memory layer

# Missing part of the code you use that create the `raster` variable

gdal.RasterizeLayer(
    raster, [1], copied_layer, burn_values=[1])
```